# how do i perform Update in hive?

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using IBM sandbox of hortonworks to perform update in hive.
I have created table with ACID properties and bucketed also.
Then I did `set hive.txn.manager` .
Then I am getting the following message:

```
FAILED: Semantic Exception [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations,while doing update.
```

Please suggest a method to update row in hive.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager` at CLI doesn't always work. 
Set this option in hive-site.xml and restart 
followed by

`set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;`

`set hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;`

These properties are required for ACID.

Also make sure that your table has the property set to `transactional`